# "Easiest to sound ok" small non-reed woodwinds to learn

Tags: learning, instruments, woodwinds, skill-level

Of all the small woodwinds from any culture, which ones are known for having the SHORTEST learning curve (for a **veteran** of any common woodwind) to achieve clean, controlled tones from 90% of playable notes?

Ok, that may be technically vague. I realize certain instruments (at least in their traditional playing style) depend on lots of textured or warbling tones. But it should be possible to get a rough idea of which ones are the easiest to play tones that are acceptable (i.e. not unnerving earsplitting baby crying).

Answer (score 8):

Well, "non-reed" eliminates most of the woodwind family, leaving only the flute family.

Recorder is pretty easy.  There's a reason it's the instrument of choice for elementary school music programs.  It takes zero embouchure (mouth position/strength) and almost no air support--you pretty much just blow into it gently and it works.

Other recorder-like instruments are going to be similar, but even less commonly used.

Comment: Another possibility that's very similar to recorder might be ocarina.

Comment: I would add that the fastest recorder to get to a pleasant sound that won't annoy the neighbors is the alto.  The soprano is physically smaller, but can be a bit shrill in the hands of a beginner.

Comment: I've been told by recorder players that the bigger recorders are easier to get a decent sound out of. It definitely matches my anecdotal experience — I was wretched at the soprano recorder in grade school, had no further experience with woodwinds, and got an alto to sound better the first time I picked it up than the soprano ever did.

Answer (score 6):

Irish whistle (aka pennywhistle aka tin whistle) is not only the easiest to learn, it's also the probably the only musical instrument in the world where you can get a professional level instrument for around US$20.

A great starter site for Irish whistle is [Chiff and Fipple](http://www.chiffandfipple.com/).

[image]

Comment: I agree, actually. Instruments like this get a bad rap because people associate them with players who have played for about 10 minutes in their entire life, but it's easy to get a great sound out of one and, hey, only 6 holes to worry about!

Comment: In this part of the world (Ireland), they're usually called tin whistles.

Comment: Eluveitie FTW. (I know, that's stupid)

Comment: You all might be interested in the melodica, too. It's probably easier to learn even than a tin whistle, but it is a reeded instrument, as a harmonica is reeded, and isn't as small. They're also fairly inexpensive, but a little higher priced on the low end than whistles. Whistles definitely fit for the desired answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to bet the recorder fits this bill.